# tqdm - multiple progress bars with nested for loops in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, tqdm

The below question is for people who use PyCharm.
There are nested `for` loops and `tqdm` is used for progress bars corresponding to each `for` loop. The code is shown below.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

for i in tqdm(range(5), desc="i", colour='green'):
    for j in tqdm(range(10), desc="j", colour='red'):
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

But the problem is, the progress bars for the inner loop appear in newline everytime there is an update in the bar as shown below.

```
i:   0%|          | 0/5 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
j:   0%|          | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
j:  10%|█         | 1/10 [00:00<00:04,  1.94it/s]
j:  20%|██        | 2/10 [00:01<00:04,  1.94it/s]
j:  30%|███       | 3/10 [00:01<00:03,  1.96it/s]
j:  40%|████      | 4/10 [00:02<00:03,  1.96it/s]
j:  50%|█████     | 5/10 [00:02<00:02,  1.97it/s]
j:  60%|██████    | 6/10 [00:03<00:02,  1.97it/s]
j:  70%|███████   | 7/10 [00:03<00:01,  1.97it/s]
j:  80%|████████  | 8/10 [00:04<00:01,  1.98it/s]
j:  90%|█████████ | 9/10 [00:04<00:00,  1.98it/s]
j: 100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:05<00:00,  1.98it/s]
i:  20%|██        | 1/5 [00:05<00:20,  5.06s/it]
j:   0%|          | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
j:  10%|█         | 1/10 [00:00<00:04,  2.00it/s]
j:  20%|██        | 2/10 [00:01<00:04,  1.99it/s]
j:  30%|███       | 3/10 [00:01<00:03,  1.99it/s]
j:  40%|████      | 4/10 [00:02<00:03,  1.99it/s]
j:  50%|█████     | 5/10 [00:02<00:02,  1.99it/s]
j:  60%|██████    | 6/10 [00:03<00:02,  1.99it/s]
j:  70%|███████   | 7/10 [00:03<00:01,  1.99it/s]
j:  80%|████████  | 8/10 [00:04<00:01,  1.99it/s]
j:  90%|█████████ | 9/10 [00:04<00:00,  1.99it/s]
j: 100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:05<00:00,  1.99it/s]
i:  40%|████      | 2/5 [00:10<00:15,  5.05s/it]
```

Setting the parameter 'position` for each loop also doesn't fix the issue.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

for i in tqdm(range(5), desc="i", colour='green', position=0):
    for j in tqdm(range(10), desc="j", colour='red', position=1):
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

How does one get the progress bar to update in the same line?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution is two fold.

1. Go to "Edit configurations". Click on the run/debug configuration that is being used. There should be an option "Emulate terminal in output console". Check that. Image added for reference.
   [image]
2. Along with the `position` argument also set the `leave` argument. The code should look like this. I have added `ncols` so that the progress bar doesn't take up whole of the console.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

for i in tqdm(range(5), position=0, desc="i", leave=False, colour='green', ncols=80):
    for j in tqdm(range(10), position=1, desc="j", leave=False, colour='red', ncols=80):
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

When the code is now run, the output of the console is as shown below.

```
i:  20%|████████▍                                 | 1/5 [00:05<00:20,  5.10s/it]
j:  60%|████████████████████████▌                | 6/10 [00:03<00:02,  1.95it/s]
```

The updates happen on the same line.

Comment: unfortunately, this checkbox does not exist when using a ssh interpreter (2020.3)

Comment: @cr0 this issue has been raised [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29204). It is up to the developers to provide this option.

Comment: @cr0 please see my answer

Comment: none of any solutions is working in 2022 idea / pycharm plugin (option emulate terminal missing; tried all combinations of Leave, Position, tqdm and tqdm.auto)

Comment: It works for me: using PyCharm 2022.3.3 (Community Edition): right click on the .py file that you want to run, select "Modify Run Configuration...": it opens a window, scroll down to the "Execution" section, and there you find "Emulate terminal in output console"

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that also works for PyCharm SSH interpreters (I am using 2021.3.1 (Professional Edition) and I don't have the option "Emulate terminal in output console"):

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(10), position=0, leave=True):
    for index in tqdm(range(10), position=0, leave=True):
        pass
```

Comment: I love you. Sincerely, someone who almost got mad when updated his pycharm